# How to clear memory after every schedule job done in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I am using node-crone to schedule my job. But I want to clear memory after every job done. So how would I do that?

Comment: There is no memory management in js, you can make sure that the object you created are not being used anywhere in the code, then the garbadge collector will free them.

Comment: It happens automatically. Once your job is finished, the process will be terminated and garbage collector takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare variables properly within a cron, function or block scope (for example `let`), then those variables will only survive as long as that scope is alive (i.e. memory cleared).

For example:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', function(){
  // y variable will be local to your function
  let y = 2;
});
```

Then, each time the function will finish running Javascript garbage collection could clean up these variable because they are no longer in use.

But, If you'll declare them otherwise they could be kept as global variables and kept alive even after the function finished.

For example:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', function(){
  // y becomes a global variable
  y = 2;
});
```

Comment: Yes, You are right, But my object value receiving from other file. In that case how I do?

Comment: deep copy it so you won't have reference to it when function is done running.